# C# List<T> Auto Increment

Tags: c#, generics

When I create a class that I have created and I create two lists with the new operator, the ID number is in the order of both when I start adding data.

After adding 10 pieces to the list 1, when I start adding 10 to List 2, ID numbers 11, 12, 13 starts to give.

Every list I want is a different way to increase the IDs.

If you can help, good work.

Sample Class

```
public class Listem
{
    private static int xid;
    public int ID;

    public DateTime Date;

    public byte Week;

    public char Process;
    public string PerName;

    public float Pips;


    public Listem(string PerName, char LongShort, byte Hafta, float Pips)
    {
        xid++;
        this.ID = xid;
        this.PerName = PerName;
        this.Process = LongShort;
        this.Week = Hafta;

        this.Pips = Pips;
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"ID : {this.ID}\tPerName : {this.PerName}   Tarih : {String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", this.Date)}\tİşlem Yönü :    {this.Process}\tHafta :     {this.Week}\tPips :     {this.Pips}";
    }
}
```

Main Program

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Listem> Liste_1 = new List<Listem>();
        List<Listem> Liste_2 = new List<Listem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Liste_1.Add(new Listem("Ahmet", '2', 2, 9F));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Liste_2.Add(new Listem("Mehmet", '3', 4, 19F));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Liste 1  ===============");
        foreach (var item in Liste_1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Liste 2  ===============");
        foreach (var item in Liste_2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
```

Result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBDvk.png)

Comment: If the ID should increment per `List` then it shouldn't be part of `Listem`. Maybe you can create another class that holds a list and the id for that list? Give it a try.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you need this auto incrementing number? What is it for?

Comment: @mjwills  My goal is to throw data simultaneously in two movements. I wanted to automatically assign the ID when assigning this data.

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? What is the **ultimate** aim?

Comment: @DennisKuypers 
I have to work with a single class
I have to do a continuous transfer of data within the Parallel. For Loop. 
Constantly creating different Class didn't make sense to me.
If you add my inexperience to this, I'm sure you'll understand the size of the problem.

Comment: @mjwills 
I have to work with a single class I have to do a continuous transfer of data within the Parallel. For Loop. Constantly creating different Class didn't make sense to me. If you add my inexperience to this

Comment: I suppose my confusion is that lists have an index **built in** to them. Why does the _individual_ list entry need to know its index? Also, what if you add a given entry to multiple lists at different positions? What should be its index then?

Comment: @mjwills  
1. Data from SQL server named Pername will be drawn in the grouped state
2. Each pername data will be drawn to a separate list by parallel processing in order from the Pername name list
3. To be subjected to the mathematical operations taken on each list

Comment: you want auto increment id? they are auto incementing, but once you are done with list 1, you should reset the counter (here xid). still I think using static memeber doing so is little odd thing to do.

Comment: @Amit What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: @UmitTerzi if Id is dependant on list (each list has ids from 1 to n) and not on object itself, Id should not be property of class. instead while adding object in list (you are using for loop) loop's counter can be id.

Answer (score 0):

To use your existing code and get the ID's to reset, you could provide a method to allow the clients to reset the `static` field `xid` on the `Listem` class back to `0` before adding items. This is not a great design, however, because it requires that the client's know they have to call this method before creating a new list.

```
public class Listem
{
    private static int xid;

    // [Other class code here]

    public static void ResetId()
    {
        xid = 0;
    }
}
```

If you want to allow the users to control the `ID` property, then you should probably just make it another public property of the class. Oh, and for that matter, you aren't using properties, you're using public fields, which is also considered a bad design. For public members, always opt for properties.

This is the quickest way to get what you want, though:

```
// Before populating a new list, always reset the xid field to '0'
Listem.ResetId();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Liste_1.Add(new Listem("Ahmet", '2', 2, 9F));
}

// Before populating a new list, always reset the xid field to '0'
Listem.ResetId();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Liste_2.Add(new Listem("Mehmet", '3', 4, 19F));
}
```

---

However a better way to do this would be to make all your public fields properties, including `ID`, and get rid of the static field:

```
public class Listem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public byte Week { get; set; }
    public char Process { get; set; }
    public string PerName { get; set; }
    public float Pips { get; set; }

    public Listem(int id, string perName, char longShort, byte hafta, float pips)
    {
        ID = id;
        PerName = perName;
        Process = longShort;
        Week = hafta;
        Pips = pips;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"ID : {ID}\tPerName : {PerName} Tarih : {Date:yyyy-MM-dd}" + 
            $"\tİşlem Yönü : {Process}\tHafta : {Week}\tPips :  {Pips}";
    }
}
```

Then you can just use the `for` loop iterator as the `ID` when creating your lists:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Liste_1.Add(new Listem(i, "Ahmet", '2', 2, 9F));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Liste_2.Add(new Listem(i, "Mehmet", '3', 4, 19F));
}
```

Then to output the lists, it would look like:

```
Liste_1.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', Console.WindowWidth));

Liste_2.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', Console.WindowWidth));
```

[image]

Comment: Listem.xid = 0;  isn't accessible

Comment: My goal is to throw data simultaneously in two movements.
I wanted to automatically assign the ID when assigning this data.
I want to be clear, I'm a beginner.

Thank you so much for giving me a detailed answer in a very short time, Rufus L.

Comment: Oh you're right, it's private. Another alternative, then, might be to add a method like `public static void ResetId() { xid = 0; }` that the client can call that resets the id. I would update the answer but I'm on my phone.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem. I've updated the answer with the method I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: The Resetid method resolves the problem if you give Liste_1 E and add and start adding data to Liste_2 after the insertion process is finished

However, when you are prompted to add data to two lists at the same time, running the continuous Resetıd method creates bigger problems.
Constant resetting of the ID numbers causes the constant starting from 0.
I think the most sensible solution is to give the ID event as a parameter from the outside.

Comment: Yeah, I think it makes sense to just make it a property if it's something that the client should be in control of.